# Save PrintPreview of an Excel file (without displaying it) as image/pdf file in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to open an Excel file in the print preview without displaying it and save it as PDF or image file.

Is it possible? How can I realize it?

Comment: Very goog question. I've never seen something like this. If you found a solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method of the Worksheet object:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Worksheet ws;  // you need to assign this somehow

ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
    @"c:\YourFile.pdf", Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard);
```